# Sort from current column from visual selection

Tags: visual-mode, command, sort, user-commands

I am trying to write a `:sort` wrapper that sorts from current column.

```
command! -bang -range=% -nargs=* Sortc exe '<line1>,<line2>sort<bang> <args> /\%' .. virtcol('.') .. 'v/'
```

E.g.

```
hello world
foo   bar
apple google
```

When the cursor is on `[w]orld`, `:Sortc` will sort into

```
foo   bar
apple google
hello world
```

It works in all cases except when in visual mode. E.g. From original text, I select all lines in virtual line mode and type `:'<,'>Sortc`, it ignores the column and sorts from beginning. i.e. `virtcol('.')`, returns 0.

Is there anyway to fix this such that it works in visual mode too?

Workaround:
After it incorrectly sorts, run the same command again placing in the correct column, without the visual mode (i.e. `@:`), then it works.

**Update:**

Using visual block selection works.

Comment: Passing an argument to sort is easier: `:command! -range=% -nargs=1 Sortc  :<line1>,<line2> !sort -k<q-args>,<q-args>`

Answer (score 1):

Before running any Ex command over a line range the cursor is always positioned to the column no. 1. So you've got your logic broken.

There can be different ways to fix it. I would probably choose taking column no. from "less-than" bookmark, and not from the cursor position (which is never a good idea anyway, as cursor can be moved to any of four(!) corners of the visual selection).

Comment: >taking column no. from "less-than" bookmark | 
How do you do that? What is "less-than" bookmark?

Comment: @balki See Reference Manual, Basic Editing, motion.txt